# ReactJS - Fade between 2 different components

Tags: reactjs, css-transitions, transition

I am trying to figure out how to fade between 2 different components with a nice easy 1 second transition.  I have played around with SwitchTransition and CSSTransition and TransitionGroup and nothing seems to work quite right for me.  It looks like SwitchTransition is what I am looking for but the only examples I can find they are just swapping out text and not whole components.

So here is the code for my two components which are shown conditionally based on state variables.  Each component has a button that will swap the state variable values so it will currently swap between the two, but it doesn't look real pretty.

```
<div className="login col-md-6 mt-5 mx-auto">
  {showLogin && (
    <LoginForm
      onLoginSubmit={onLoginSubmit}
      email={email}
      setEmail={setEmail}
      password={password}
      setPassword={setPassword}
      showPasswordReset={showPasswordReset}
    />
  )}
  {showForgotPassword && (
    <ForgotPasswordForm
      onPasswordResetSubmit={onPasswordResetSubmit}
      setShowForgotPassword={setShowForgotPassword}
    />
  )}
</div>
```

Comment: Can you also share CSS for transitions?

Comment: That's part of what I'm struggling with.  I mean I can  add something like `transition: all 1s ease-in;` to both divs, but that never seems to work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use react-spring to animate your components, first

```
import { animated, useTransition } from "react-spring";
```

then inside your component

```
const [showLogin, set] = useState(false);

const toggle = () => {
    set(!showLogin);
};

const transitions = useTransition(showLogin, null, {
        from: { position: "absolute", opacity: 0 },
        enter: { opacity: 1 },
        leave: { opacity: 0 }
      });
```

and then you will render your components, make sure to replace `div` with `animated.div`

```
<div className="login col-md-6 mt-5 mx-auto">
    {transitions.map(({ item, key, props }) =>
        item ? (
            <LoginForm //animated.div
                onLoginSubmit={onLoginSubmit}
                email={email}
                setEmail={setEmail}
                password={password}
                setPassword={setPassword}
                showPasswordReset={showPasswordReset}
            />
        ) : (
            <ForgotPasswordForm //animated.div
                onPasswordResetSubmit={onPasswordResetSubmit}
                setShowForgotPassword={toggle}
            />
        )
    )}
</div>
```

I made a simple example, you can check it out [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/fade-between-2-different-components-ex30j?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: how would I increase the fade time?

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out from google.  `const transitions = useTransition(show, null, {
    from: { position: "absolute", opacity: 0 },
    enter: { opacity: 1 },
    leave: { opacity: 0 },
    config: { duration: 1000 }
  });`
Thank you so much!

Comment: add config to transitions
const transitions = useTransition(showLogin, null, {
        from: { position: "absolute", opacity: 0 },
        enter: { opacity: 1 },
        leave: { opacity: 0 },
 config: { duration: 300 } // here you can change the time 
      });

Comment: One more question, do you know if there is a way to not have it fade in on page load?

Comment: add "initial" to "transitions", it will overwrite "from" at the first load only so no animation will occur on page load 
`initial: { position: "absolute", opacity: 1 }`